# Change ALL pushed commit messages

Tags: git, git-filter

I recently moved from TFS to GIT and all our commit messages are formatted "^88888 my commit message" I am trying to change the ^ in ALL git messages to a #.

Looking at the git documentation I found I could use a git-filter command but I am not sure how to correctly use it to change just part of the commit message and retain the rest recursively.

Anyone done this or know if git-filter is the correct command?

Comment: The command is `git filter-branch`.  Neither filter-branch nor rebase can actually *change* any existing commit; both work by, instead, copying existing commits to *new* (but different) commits.  If you run this over every commit in a repository, you get, in effect, a new, different, unrelated repository.  If that's OK, the filter you want within `git filter-branch` is the `--msg-filter`.  If your repository contains tags and you want to move the tags to the new commits, you will also need `--tag-name-filter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use git rebase - i.

It will let you modify the commit message as well.